# How to index video subtitles in Alfresco?

Tags: search, indexing, alfresco, caption, subtitle

I'm looking for a way to index video subtitles within Alfresco.  Ideally I'd like to return the specific point in a video where the caption was found.

Does anyone know of a way to do this with standard .mp4 and .srt files?

Comment: Do you already have a tool that can extract the text of the subtitles along with their position? Or can you find one? That'll be the first step!

Comment: I can write a script to pull the times and string contents from the srt files.  Nothing very elegant at this point.  How would advise indexing a video to sync with the separate srt text?

Comment: How are you planning to do the link to the specific point in the file?